# I am missing the 32 bits librarires: libc.so.6

Tags: 14.04, macbook

I'm new to linux. I installed ubuntu 14.04 64bit yesterday on my macbook pro 11,3. I don't know what i did wrong but i always get this libc.so.6 error when I try to open steam. I've tried many solutions from linux forums and askUbuntu but noting seems to work for me.

Thank you for your time.

when I click on steam icon I get this pop-up terminal :

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

i run these command by entering my sudo password and get this :

```
    ...............................................................................................W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64  (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going   to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libllvm3.4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                libtxc-dxtn0:i386

libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
                    Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-present0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb-sync1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxshmfence1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                             libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
                    Conflicts: libgl1
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1:i386
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 xserver-xorg-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 0~)
                       Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 0~)
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has  an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
Press return to continue:
```

after pressing return i get the " You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run: libc.so.6 " error i was talking earlier

here is some more info on my situation
 command:

```
jhon@jhon:~$ sudo apt-get install package-name
[sudo] password for jhon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt  /sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package package-name
```

this might help you to help me :

```
jhon@jhon:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
# deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/motorbike/ubuntu trusty main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
# deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/motorbike/ubuntu trusty main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

i tried this :

```
jhon@jhon:~$ sudo apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: If my question seems confusing or lack crucial information feel free to ask me or message me. I'll give the needed info.